# Where can I find the list of Model Field Attributes for Flectra?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, flectra

I am currently developing some modules in Flectra but I am new to the environment and the documentation. The Docs mention that the Module Fields have common attributes, but it won't provide a list of all the attributes..
Can someone help me figure this out?
Thanks!

Link to the Docs: https://doc.flectrahq.com/1.0/howtos/backend.html#common-attributes

Comment: Common field attributes are described in the [field](https://doc.flectrahq.com/1.0/reference/orm.html#basic-fields) section, and specific field attributes are described for each field type separately.

Comment: Thank you! Thats what I didn't find. You helped a lot;)